# Can't drop milliseconds from timestamp

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, amazon-redshift

I have this `date_created` as `2015-12-02 00:58:07.000000`.
So I've searched SO and Google for a while now and I've tried everything at this point it feel like ....

`date_created::timestamp(0)`

or `to_char(date_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::timestamp(0)`

or `DATE_TRUNC('second', date_created)::timestamp(0)` return

```
[XX000] ERROR: Assert
Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error:
Assert code: 1 ...
```

...

`to_timestamp(date_created)::timestamp(0)` returns

```
[42883] ERROR: function to_timestamp(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

...

`date_trunc('minute', date_created::timestamp)`

or

`date_trunc('minute', date_created)` return

`2015-12-02 00:58:00.000000`

I just want to drop to stupid milliseconds while still keeping the data type as datetime or timestamp. Does anyone have any other tricks? Or is that just not a thing that's possible?

Comment: For formatting you should use to_char(), but without casting it back to a timestamp.

Comment: You can't. The only way to do this is to format to a string.

Comment: Why does `date_created::timestamp(0)` not work for you? As in `select now()::timestamp(0) 11/16/2023 08:13:20`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i'm not sure. It just returns a super helpful "ERROR: Assert" error %\

Comment: Well from here [Date/time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html#r_Datetime_types-timestamp) it does not look like Redshift supports precision specification for `timestamp/timestamptz`. In fact the docs say: *If you insert a date into a TIMESTAMPTZ column, or a date with a partial timestamp, the value is implicitly converted into a full timestamp value. This full timestamp value has default values (00) for missing hours, minutes, and seconds.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can influence the way PostgreSQL renders a timestamp as string is by setting the parameter `datestyle`, and none of the settings will suppress the display of fractional seconds.

If you have special requirements for rendering a timestamp as a string, use `to_char` like in your second attempt, but omit the additional cast to `timestamp`, as it will undo your effort.